# ValidationExpression (asp.net RegularExpressionValidator) to not allow repeated numbers

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox that allows at the most 9 numbers.
I also need to make sure that the numbers are not repeated. Eg: Do not allow 111111111, 222222222, and so on. Can anyone tell me ValidationExpression that can help me achieve that.

Currently I am using

```
ValidationExpression="^([0-9\s]{9})$"
```

to restrict the user to 9 numbers.
I need to add a way to not allow repeated numbers, hopefully using ValidationExpression.

PLEASE HELP!!

Note: Please don't be quick to rate me. If this question is not clear, please put it in the reply and I will try to improve. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

from your regex : ValidationExpression="^([0-9\s]{9})$"

which allowed numbers [0-9] and "space" for 9 characters.

You may use max char allow to limit how many characters are allowed,
Plus using allowed pattern.
But you may not able to detect if user input some number such as :

123456789

987654321

123123123

121212121

111112222

---

Using this will detect five repeated numbers.

```
([0-9])\1\1\1\1
```

But you may need to consider other checking method.

Comment: Thank you @VDWWD for editing my question. I tried above expression, but it did not work. Can anyone suggest any other way to validate my scenerio